# varnish cache - how to exclude an element (i.e iframe ) from cache

Tags: varnish

we cache our web site with varnish. But we want to exclude some html element (i.e. iframes) from cache. How can we configure VLC as we want? Thank you all already now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/42164/varnish-configuration-to-only-cache-for-non-logged-in-users) serverfault question and you should get the idea. it does nearly the same, you just have to replace the conditions in `vcl_recv` with your url which is displayed in the iframe.